# Incremental data load/processing

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

We have a lot of applications that are tracked by Azure Application Insight. We have configured continuous export to Azure Blob Storage. These data are **partitioned by an export date**. The folder structure have format

> {yyyy-MM-dd}/{guid}.blob

There is a problem, the partition key rely on an export date (not on an events dates within *.blob files).

So the file that is placed to the folder

> /2016-11-05/

can contain events for dates

> 2016-11-09, 2016-11-11, 2016-11-12

We would like to have these data in Azure Data Lake Database to analyze them with Azure Data Lake Analytics. Also we would like to have an event table **partitioned by an event generation time.**

To orchestrate the entire ETL process we have choosen ADF. We like the incremental model, scheduling and concurency model. We have choosen a **data slice ~ 1 day**. One of the ADF's requirements: every activity in a pipeline should be **repeatable** (if i will schedule rerun for a random data slice, it should be reprocessed consistently, for example cleanup an old data, and load a new data).

So we have the pipeline with these activities:

1) Data Movement: jsons blobs ---> csv datalake store file system, the result csv files have **the same partitioning key as the source data, aligned to an export date**.

2) U-SQL Activity. We planned to invoke an U-SQL job and pass the parameters SliceStart, SliceEnd pointed to the current data slice. When source's and target's partitioning key are aligned, we can just truncate partition / reload partition. But when these partitions are missaligned there is not so good.

Looks like there is problem to implement **repeatable** U-SQL step in the case due to:

- missaligned partitioning key (export date vs event date)
- lack of dynamic U-SQL

But the root cause here is partition's misalignment.

I have only ideas:

- an additional task that will repartition the source app insight's data
- crazy dances with dynamic U-SQL emulation https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa475035-2d57-49b8-bdff-9cccc9c8b48f/usql-loading-a-dynamic-set-of-files?forum=AzureDataLake

I would be happy if someone gave me idea how to solve the problem. Ideally we should avoid massive reload/rescans of data.

Comment: So what's the question please?

Comment: Accordingly to the root cause, i think the question is how to repartition the data effitiently.